# Detailing a proposition about option pricing model coherence

Tags: options, black-scholes, implied-volatility, volatility-skew

On page 4 of [this paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2097921), the author states the following:

> "Looking at the limit case, when the strike tends towards 0, we should have the
>   price of a forward contract and it should not depend on the equity skew around 0."

I cannot interpret mathematically what the author stated. Could you please provide a mathematical explanation of what the author said in words?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of a call option at expiry is $V=\mathrm{max}(0, S_t-K)$.

If you set $K=0$, then you have $V=\mathrm{max}(0, S_t)$, and since $S\geqslant0$, $\mathrm{max}(0, S_t) = S_t$ - i.e. ie's equivalent to holding the stock, which at expiry you'll expect to be worth the whatever the forward is.

Comment: The price today of a contract that will pay off $S_T$ at maturity is, pretty much by definition, the  forward price.

Comment: yes, exactly. Is it not clear that that's what i meant?

Comment: Same idea, different words.